# Node.js: Failed to lookup view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is what I get when I run 'Node server.js' and get "listening" as a response, and then open my browser to find this:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "./login/login" in views directory "C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\views"
   at EventEmitter.app.render (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:555:17)
   at ServerResponse.res.render (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:938:7)
   at C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\server.js:226:7
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at next (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
   at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
   at C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
   at Function.proto.process_params (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
   at next (C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
```

I moved the 'views' folder from 'C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\app\server\views' to 'C:\Users\Ghanem\cloud1\views' but still the same error occurs (I moved it back now).

Here's the line of code of "./login/login" from **server.js**:

```
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  // Show form, default value = current username
  res.render("./login/login", { "username": req.session.username, "error": null });
});
```

Here's the structure:

```
./
  app/
     public/
           css/
              style.css
              style.styl

           img/
              glyph.png
              glyph1.png

           js/
             controllers/
                        homeController.js
                        loginController.js
                        signupController.js

             form-validators/
                            accountValidator.js
                            emailValidator.js
                            loginValidator.js
                            resetValidator.js
             views/
                  home.js
                  login.js
                  reset.js
                  signup.js


             vendor/
                   bootstrap.min.css
                   bootstrap-modal.js
                   bootstrap-transition.js
                   jquery.form.js
                   jquery.min.js


     server/
           modules/
                   account-manager.js
                   country-list.js
                   email-dispatcher.js
                   email-settings.js
           views/
                el/
                Models/
                      alert.jade
                      confirm.jade
                      form-errors.jade
                      lost-password.jade
                      reset-password.jade

                404.jade
                account.jade
                home.jade
                layout.jade
                login.jade
                print.jade
                reset.jade
                signup.jade             


       router.js
       router.js.b


           router.js
           router.js.b
```

How can I fix this problem? Keep in mind that I already moved the views folder to the root folder but somehow it wasn't detected.

Comment: What do you set for `app.set('views');`?

Comment: I don't see a view called `/login/login`

Comment: @vanadium23 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

So if you write:

```
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  // Show form, default value = current username
  res.render("login/login", { "username": req.session.username, "error": null });
});
```

Template must be in `app/server/views/login/login.ejs`, if your `index.js` are in app/server folder.

Comment: @JesseJames so then change `login/login` just to `login`